# How to put Circle class into layout

Tags: android

I want to put Circle class into my layout. I tried it but app got stopped on creating. I think the problem is in xml code in the first line which is under. Kindly guide me.

```
<com.package.Circle
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/circle"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp" />
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.zohaib.animatedcircle.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

    <com.package.Circle
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/circle"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Circle.java

```
package com.example.zohaib.animatedcircle;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class Circle extends View {

    private static final int START_ANGLE_POINT = 90;

    private final Paint paint;
    private final RectF rect;

    private float angle;

    public Circle(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        final int strokeWidth = 40;

        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
        //Circle color
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);

        //size 200x200 example
        rect = new RectF(strokeWidth, strokeWidth, 200 + strokeWidth, 200 + strokeWidth);

        //Initial Angle (optional, it can be zero)
        angle = 120;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawArc(rect, START_ANGLE_POINT, angle, false, paint);
    }

    public float getAngle() {
        return angle;
    }

    public void setAngle(float angle) {
        this.angle = angle;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.zohaib.animatedcircle;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        Circle circle = (Circle) findViewById(R.id.circle);

        CircleAngleAnimation animation = new CircleAngleAnimation(circle, 240);
        animation.setDuration(1000);
        circle.startAnimation(animation);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: The XML element needs to start with `<com.example.zohaib.animatedcircle.Circle`, not `<com.package.Circle`.

Comment: thanks it working. kindly reply as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML element name needs to be the fully qualified class name of your custom `View` class. In this case, it would be `com.example.zohaib.animatedcircle.Circle`, instead of `com.package.Circle`.

```
<com.example.zohaib.animatedcircle.Circle
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/circle"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp" />
```